# ajax function not executing properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

This is my .ctp file where on the click of submit button it should save the data in database. But when the function is going on the controller it is not returning any value, so it is not going in the success function of ajax. And I have no idea whether it is going in the controller function and returning any value.

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function(e){
            var value1=$('#nname').val(); 
            //alert(value1);
            $.ajax({  
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",  
            evalScripts: true,
            url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Partconfs','action'=>'addlot'));?>',
            data: ({name1:value1}),  
            success: function(result){ 
            console.log(result);
            alert(result);
            if(result==2)
            {
            $('*').css('cursor','auto');
            }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Associated .php file where I am simply saving the lot_no in the lot table in the database and echoing 2.so it should return to the success function of ajax.but there is some problem and it is not returning to ajax success function.

```
public function addlot()

        {

         $this->loadModel('lot');
         $this->layout = 'ajax';
         $this->autoRender = false;
         $lotno=$this->request->data['name1'];
         $loc = $this->Auth->user('location');
         $acc=array('lot_no'=>$lotno,'location'=>$loc);
         $this->lot->save($acc);
         $this->loadModel('lot');
        $this->lot->recursive=0;
         $this->set('lots',$this->lot->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('location'=>$loc))));
             echo 2;
              }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to swap either the inner or outer single quotes `'` to double quotes `"` in the url `url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Partconfs','action'=>'addlot'));?>',`

Comment: ... or should there really be inner quotes on those lambda methods??

Comment: it is not working whether it is single quotes or double quotes

Comment: I assume that code piece is from PHP, so how does that URL look like after being rendered in the web browser? ... and if it is how it looks in the browsers, it won't work as that is PHP code and not a valid URL

Comment: you can try static url insted of "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Partconfs','action'=>'addlot'));?>" to check your ajax working or not.

Comment: Try to check if the request sends by network tab or by putting a breakpoint in the server code

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change

```
url: '<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Partconfs','action'=>'addlot'));?>',
```

to

```
url: "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Partconfs','action'=>'addlot'));?>",
```

and in order to debug your ajax you can check **"Network"** tab of your browser and choose your ajax call from there and check what error you are getting. Please find the attached image for your reference

[image]

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use `json_encode()` instead of manually putting quotes around PHP generated strings. Besides that, single or double quotes, that doesn't really matter here, as they are quotes in JavaScript, and the inline PHP isn't affected by it at all, it just messes up StackOverflows syntax highlighting as it isn't context aware.